# Is is possible to move or clone an Azure web app to another azure account

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I have new Azure account, I need to move my web app to, do we have a way to move it by using Azure or need to deploy again.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

By new Azure account, I assume it's a new subscription as well. It's possible with a few limitations, and you need to move all dependencies with it. Basically, you need to have everything under the same resource group, and you move the entire resource group objects to the new location. If you have a dependency that can't be moved, then you can't move the Web App and you have to perform the data content migration manually. Follow the steps below:

[Move resources to new resource group or subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources)

You also want to make sure your login credential have administrative (owner or contributor) privileges on both subscriptions and that they rest under the same directory.

[How to associate or add an Azure subscription to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory)

Comment: If the subscriptions are not in a same Tenant(Directory), the resources cannot be moved to another subscription.